# python-get physical disk info from logical path

Tags: python, linux, windows, wmi

I have the logical paths. For instance:-
path1='C:/abc', path2='E:/xyz'

I want to check if both of them reside on same physical disk.

Or in general I want to map a logical path to associated physical drives.

I would also want to do the same for linux.
For now I use "os.stat(path).st_dev" to get the device id. But the id seems to be different for logical disks on same same physical drive. So it doesn't actully work for me. Is there a better or direct solution to it.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning my efforts. I tried using wmi and it solved my problem. But again stuck for the same in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
   key = ''
    for physical_disk in w.Win32_DiskDrive():
    logical_disks = []
    for partition in physical_disk.associators ("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
        for logical_disk in partition.associators ("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
            key = logical_disk.Description
            if key not in all_logical_disks:
                all_logical_disks[key] = []
            logical_disks.append(logical_disk.Caption)
    if logical_disks:
        all_logical_disks[key].append(logical_disks)
```

This helped me to get a dict of type: {u'Local Fixed Disk': [[u'C:', u'D:'],[u'E:', u'F:']]} which grouped logical patitions in different physical disks. Now I can compare if the logical paths lie in the same list.